# How do i import .tmx assets from Tiled into Monogame using XTiled

Tags: c#, monogame, tiled

How do i import .tmx assets frome Tiled into Monogame using XTiled? I am trying to get the Content pipeline to use a custom processor for the .tmx files provided by XTiled. I looked at Monogame's documentation on their content pipeline but i don't think that the section has been updated in a while.

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you download the DLL? If so, did you unblock it?

Comment: I copied the project to Source Tree, built the project, and got the DLL's. What do you mean unblock it?

Comment: NTFS has a weird property to block content downloaded from the web for security purposes. XNA pipeline uses reflection on the DLL, but the content is blocked, thus it cannot see its custom-defined processors/importers.

Comment: How do i unblock it?